# Total Coloring of a graph with $\Delta\ge\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Consider an even vertex transitive graph $G$, which is not complete, with order $n$ and  degree $k$ greater than or equal to half the order. By Hajnal-Szemeredi theorem, we could partition the vertices into $k+1$ color classes, where $k$ be the maximum degree, which implies that each color class has a maximum of two vertices. Let the color classes be enumerated as $[a_1,b_1], [a_2,b_2],......[a_k,b_k]$, where the vertices in each class (square brackets) are separated by commas. Note that some vertices may be null also.

Now, we add  a hypothetical vertex, say $v_1$, which we make adjacent all the vertices $a_1, a_2, a_3,....,a_k$. We consider the induced subgraph formed by the vertices $a_1, a_2, a_3,....,a_k,v_1$ and call it $A$, and see that it has maximum degree k+1. We edge-color the graph A with $k+2$ colors, and give the vertices the same color as the color of the edges between the vertex $v$ and those same vertices. We repeat a similar process by adding another hypothetical vertex, say $v_2$ and forming a graph $B$ by making it adjacent to all the vertices $b_1, b_2, b_3,....., b_k$. I think that  the graph A (or B) is isomorphic to an induced subgraph of B (or A)(by vertex transitivity, as neighborhood of any vertex is similar).

Now, we consider the graph $X=G-E(A)-E(B)$. This is bipartite. We list edge color this graph with lists of cardinality $k$ where the lists are so chosen (the lists consist of the colors used in the edge coloring of $A$ and $B$  along with two extra colors which we add) that the colors on the edges of $X$  obey the total coloring condition. Then, I think the graph $G$ would be totally colored with $k+4$ colors.

Any mistake in the above reasoning? If the reasoning is invalid by the two graphs $A$ and $B$ being not similar (one graph being not isomorphic to a subgraph of $A$), could be it be valid for Cayley graphs? Specifically whether we can have lists of cardinality $k$ colors to color the edges of $X$?  Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: What do you mean by "even graph"?

Comment: If I understand the term "total coloring" correctly, when you edge-color the graph $A$ with $k+1$ colors, the vertices of $A$ cannot have the colors of the edges.

Comment: @LeechLattice actually i want to totally color the graph $G$. Since the vertex $v_1$ and $v_2$ do not belong to $G$, so i can always give the color of the edges $v-a_i$ to the corresponding vertices $a_i$

Comment: @bof by even graph, i mean a graph of even order

Comment: Why must the colour classes have size at most 2?  There are lots of them, but one could be large if many are singletons.

Comment: @BenBarber yes, in fact the graph may well be even bipartite. But, my argument is that it can always be partitioned by the Brooks theorem into $k$ classes such that any class has at most two vertices

Comment: I see now: it's what I know as Hajnal–Szemerédi (which I am more used to thinking about in the complement, where we're covering by cliques).